# Chrome Plugin Storage (across updates)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome.storage to store some persistent data for Chrome Plugins, but I see that this stored data is lost during the plugin update. When a new version of the plugin package is published on the chrome-store, it is usually pushed to the users, and in that process the older setting, stored variables are not surviving across the updates. Is there a different API or different usage / work-flow that could help?

Tried the chrome.storage.sync but the updates still erase the stored data and start afresh.

Comment: There must be a mistake in your code or a bug in the browser, because this storage is preserved for all other extensions on update.

Comment: You're right. I am initializing the persistent storage variables in the "onInstalled" event, which may be resetting whenever the plugin is updated. I did that because if I fetch the variable/storage before it was created, it errors out, so I was init-ing it in the onInstalled handler.